# Kotlin to filter certain options using When

Tags: kotlin

How can I use When in Kotlin to do something if not in some certain conditions? for example

```
  when(condition : String){
    //not "A","B","C" -> return
    // else -> continue to do something
}
```

I've tried some keyword or operator such as ! or not, but doesn't
work

Comment: your "not" then is the `else`-case, right?

Comment: alternatively: `when { condition !in someCases /* A, B, C */ -> return; else -> /* continue */ }`?

Comment: and finally: `if (condition !in someCases /* A, B, C */) return; /* continue to do something */`

Answer (score 1):

For the specific case in your question, here are two ways I would do it:

```
when (myString) {
    !in arrayOf("A", "B", "C") -> return
    else -> {
        // continue to do something
    }
}
```

Just flipping the condition (swap the order of your code):

```
when (myString) {
    "A", "B", "C" -> {
        // continue to do something
    }
    else -> { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if not in some certain conditions?

Exactly that.

let's suppose you have this :

```
  val value  = 5
```

to check if something is within a certain range of values:

```
      when (value in 0..5) {
        true -> {}
        else -> {}
    }
```

alternatively:

```
    when (value !in 0..5) {
        true -> {}
        else -> {}
    }
```

but making use of negative logic is sometimes harder to read or follow, so the first approach would probably be easier to understand perhaps.

similary for strings:

```
 val range = arrayListOf("a", "b", "c")
    when (value in range) {
        true -> {}
        else -> {}
    }
```

you could also expand this further:

```
  val value = "hello"

    val allowedRange = arrayListOf("a", "b", "c")
    val excludedRange = arrayListOf("x", "y", "z")
    when (value) {
        in allowedRange -> {

        }

        in excludedRange -> {

        }
        else -> {}
    }
```

Comment: Oh, you mean I can build a list first and put all the conditions I want into it. I’ve never thought of it, that seams work.

Comment: well it allows you to create really readable code, `when (value in acceptableRange)` or `when (value !in acceptableRange)` makes it pretty easy for the next person to understand what you're trying to say, which is the first part of my answer, we're now essentially writing exactly what you want : `if not in some certain conditions?` can also just be an if, no need for a when, but you can adapt it to fit that case too